# Change number of elements per page with <%= will_paginate %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using the `will_paginate` gem. The default is 30 elements per page. How do I customize this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your controller is called User, you can do something like this in your controller:
`@users = User.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'name ASC'` This will show 10 results per page.

In your view:
`<%= will_paginate @users %>`

Answer (score 4):

See the `per_page` option here:

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki

It will allow you to change the number displayed per page, for anytime that model is paginated.

For a controller/action specific approach see Raunak's answer.